# Windows Powershell Script for testing a list of Redirected URL's

Tags: windows, powershell

I want to a Windows PowerShell script that can test a list of URL's which are redirected. I want there status code and there target URL.
I am getting for a single URL, however unable to get it for a list of URL's.
If anyone can help me with the above.

Comment: What have you tried already?  Can you post the code that's failing?

Answer (score 1):

Create a `[WebRequest]` object and set the `AllowAutoRedirect` property to `$false`:

```
# You could read this list from a file if necessary
$urls = @('http://stackoverflow.com/')

foreach($url in $urls){
  try{
    # Create WebRequest object, disallow following redirects
    $request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $request.AllowAutoRedirect = $false

    # send the request and obtain the HTTP response
    $response = $request.GetResponse()
    $statusCode = $response.StatusCode

    # Create a new output object with the needed details
    [pscustomobject]@{
      Original = $url
      Target = if($statusCode -ge 300 -and $statusCode -lt 400) {
        $response.Headers['Location']
      };
      StatusCode = +$statusCode
    }
  }
  finally {
    if($response -is [IDisposable]){
      # Dispose of the response stream (otherwise we'll be blocking the tcp socket until it times out)
      $response.Dispose()
    }
  }
}
```

The `+` in front of `$statusCode` ensures conversion to the numeric response code (ie `301`) instead of it's name (`MovedPermanently`)

Comment: Great, I'm learning new things. Why `+` io `[int]`? It's the same effect but shorter or is there another reason?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers no, just the first thing that came to mind, casting to `[int]`, converting `-as [int]` or referencing `$statusCode.value__` would all be valid :)

Comment: Thanks @MathiasR.Jessen for the script. I need one additional thing in the code. I want to check the redirects URL for 20 languages. For that I have used "locale" condition in my redirects. However, unable to identify condition in powershell to check those 20 languages URL.
For eg: if I enter "https://www.example.com/locale/abc/ab"
Then it should check for all 20 countries that what is the response code and target URL. So, which condition do I need to add in above powershell script.

Comment: @SA if the locale is part of the URL then that's just a question of generating those urls before running the code I posted. `$urls = 'en,de,it,fr,es' -split ',' |ForEach-Object {"https://example.com/${_}/abc/ab"}`