# PowerShell for Checking Multilingual URL Redirects

Tags: powershell

I was trying to check a list of Multilingual URL, whether they are redirecting properly or not. I want Original URL, Status Code and Target URL as output of that list of URL's using Powershell. I have tried the below script however it doesn't work for me.

```
$linksFilePath = "myinputlistfile.txt"
$outCSVPath = "outputfile.csv"

get-content $linksFilePath |
 Foreach { $uri = $_;  

if ($uri -contains "locale")
{
    $AllLanguage = ("en", "en-US","en-CA","en-AU","en-GB","de-DE","fr-BE","ms-MY","se-NO","zh-SG","pt-PT","de-CH","es-ES","fr-CA","fr-FR","it-IT","ja-JP","nl-NL","pt-BR","zh-CN") -split ','
    foreach ($i in $AllLanguage)
    {
        $newuri = $uri.Replace("locale" , $i)
        try { 
            Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $newuri -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -UseBasicParsing
            Write-output ("$($newuri), StatusCode, $($_.Headers["Location"]), Error")
            } 
        catch 
        { 
            New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ Error = $_ } 
        } 

    }
}
else{
        try { 
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri -Method HEAD -MaximumRedirection 0 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -UseBasicParsing 
        Write-Output ("$(uri), StatusCode, $($_.Headers["Location"]), Error")
        } 
        catch 
        { 
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{ Error = $_ } 
        }
    }

      } |
 Export-Csv $outCSVPath
 Write-Host "Execution Completed"
```

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60547691/windows-powershell-script-for-testing-a-list-of-redirected-urls/60548017#60548017)? And what does "it doesn't work for me." mean - are you getting errors? Unexpected results? Please tell us _what's wrong_ if you want help fixing it :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I am getting unexpected results results, instead of 3 expected columns 11 column are getting generated, and all of them consists of raw data eg: "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebCmdletElementCollection". I just wanted 3 columns in my output: Original URL, Status Code, Target URL.